# Get ROI from face landmark points cv2 dlib

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

Am using following code to draw facial landmark points using dlib , on to the frames captured from webcam in realtime, now what am looking for is to get the ROI that bounds all the points complying the face , the code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import dlib
import numpy
from imutils.video import FPS
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
import imutils

PREDICTOR_PATH = "./shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)
cascade_path = 'cascade/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)

webcam = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
fps = FPS().start()

while True:
    im = webcam.read()
    im = imutils.resize(im, width=400)

    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(im, 1.3, 5)
    if len(faces) != 0:
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces.astype(long):
            rect = dlib.rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h)
            #cv2.imwrite('face.png', rect)
            get_landmarks = numpy.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(im, rect).parts()])

        for idx, point in enumerate(get_landmarks):
            pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
            cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,
                        fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,
                        fontScale=0.4,
                        color=(0, 0, 255))
           # cv2.drawContours(im, [pos], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
#            hullIndex = cv2.convexHull(pos, returnPoints=False)
#            cv2.imwrite('face.png', hullIndex)
            cv2.circle(im, pos, 3, color=(0, 255, 255))
    cv2.imshow('Result', im)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    fps.update()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to dump the facial landmark points into image file. but am unable to understand , how  I can extract ROI from these landmark points and then dump to file using

> cv2.imwrite('face.png', hullIndex)

, but here I don't want the rectangle drwaned using

> faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(im, 1.3, 5)

, I want only the shape that circumfencec the facial landmark points, the output of the above code looks like below.

[image]

So, just dump only points that circumferences the facial edge points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the 68 facial landmarks from the predictor, You may simply iterate over all the points and update the `minX, minY, maxX, maxY` which after the iteration would yield the bounding rect exactly enclosing all the facial landmarks.

You may also use `cv2.boundingRect(points)` but you need to transform all the points to a numpy array before passing to this method.

But I would recommend you the first solution and it is fairly easy to implement as

```
minX, minY = 10000000, 10000000
maxX, maxY = 0, 0
for point in get_landmarks:
    if point[0] < minX:
        minX = point[0]
    elif point[0] > maxX:
        maxX = point[0]
    elif point[1] < minY:
        minY = point[1]
    elif point[1] > maxY:
        maxY = point[1]

bounding_rect = [minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY]
```

Comment: Yes, I tried given solution but it's not dumping roi, instead created black color image only!

Comment: giving this eception:    if point[0] < minX:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @U.Swap in Your case `point[0]` is not accessing the X coordinate of a given point, but a whole numpy array kindly see your `get_landmarks` structure and iterate accodingly.

Comment: if point[0,0] < minX:
                    minX = point[0,0]
                elif point[0,0] > maxX:
                    maxX = point[0,0]
                elif point[0,1] < minY:
                    minY = point[0,1]
                elif point[0,1] > maxY:
                    maxY = point[0,1]
            bounding_rect = [minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY]

            cv2.imwrite('face.png', bounding_rect)

Comment: this what i tried, but throws: TypeError: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: Serious Issues with your understanding of numpy matrices, Firstly try to iterate the feature points by yourself and see if you can get `x` and `y` of each point.

Comment: Thanks, for your help man, I finally managed to make it work.